# How to update the new database to the live site without affecting the existing database

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

We added some more functionality and database tables in existing drupal site, the site already is in live and having few registered users and their settings. Now we want to add these new functionality to the existing one without affecting the existing data in mysql database.

I am scared to update the new database because there might be chance to delete the existing data in our database. How can we do this?

Comment: What kind of database (schema) changes are you referring to?

Comment: @MikePurcell: well in my existing site(live) having some 90 database tables and after added some more modules now the database table count is 130. I dont know How to update these new database tables into with existing database?

Comment: Did you add the new tables by means of a plugin install? Or are they all custom made?

Comment: @MikePurcell:  No i did not create any custom module. All are drupal modules.

Comment: You could create a snapshot of production data, and bring it into your dev (or qa) environment, and install the new plugins. Then run some tests to make sure all is well. I was coming at it from a strictly mysql vantage point, so hopefully a drupal expert will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Modules can not only create tables, but also alter tables and can install records in existing tables (variables, menu items, enabled/disabled flag in the system table, etc...) so while there are 40 new tables there are likely multiple changes/records somewhere in the other 90 tables as well.

I recommend taking @MikePurcell's advice and making a back-up of the existing production database (and module files if you are applying any updates to modules that are on both the production and development sites), installing the new modules, and testing to make sure everything is still working properly.  Unfortunately if you've customized those modules you'll need to re-apply your customizations.